# constraint check against values of foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have these two tables

Table: `Guards`

- ID int
- Name varchar
- Rank int

Table: `Squads`

- SquadId
- Leader
- SquadName

The `Leader` column points to the `ID` column in the `Guard` table and I'm trying to create a constraint that checks if the `Rank` column linked to the guard id provided as the leader is a specific value (in this case 1)

Is this possible or do I have to use a trigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `CHECK` constraint. I'd wrap the constraint into a function since you need to check another table's value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckLeaderRank
(@LeaderID INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @value INTEGER;
DECLARE @MinimumRank INTEGER = 3;

SET @value = CASE WHEN (SELECT RANK FROM Guards WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE Id = @LeaderID) >= @MinimumRank THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

RETURN @value
END
```

The function will check if the guard's `Rank` is high enough : make sure to set `@MinimumRank` to the proper value or, even better, to fetch it from another table.

Now add the constraint to your `Squads` table.

```
ALTER TABLE Squads
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_rank CHECK (dbo.CheckLeaderRank(i) = 1)
```

Comment: What happens if a Guard's rank changes? Will the constraint be checked, since it's not on the Guards table?